# What is the following Calculation about?

Tags: logarithms

i'm going through some homework, but there is one thing i don't understand.
Our task is to explain the following calculation:

Given: $h(x) = \ln(x^4)$

I.
$ 
\begin{align}
h(x) = t(x) &\Rightarrow \ln(x^4) = mx = 4 \\
&\Rightarrow x^4 = e^4 \\
&\Rightarrow  x = e \quad \textrm{or}\quad  x = -e
\end{align}
$

I am confused about the line:  $\Rightarrow \ln(x^4) = mx = 4$.

II.

$ 
\begin{align}
h'(x) = m &\Rightarrow 4/x = m  \\
&\Rightarrow x = 4/m \\
&\Rightarrow t(x) = \frac{4x}{e}
\end{align}
$

I just can't figure out what hes doing here :/

Comment: Hi testiii, I converted your math to LaTeX.  Can you make sure I copied the problem correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the determination of the point at which the tangent to the graph of $h$ passes through the origin.

Hence one is looking for $x_0$ and $m$ such that $h(x_0)=mx_0$ and $h'(x_0)=m$. Then the line of equation $y=t(x)$ with $t(x)=mx$ is the tangent to the graph of $h$ at the point $x_0$.

Since $h(x)=4\log x$ and $h'(x)=4/x$, this reads as $4\log x_0=mx_0$ and $4/x_0=m$. Hence $x_0m=4$, $\log x_0=1$, $x_0=\mathrm e$, $m=4/\mathrm e$, and the equation of the tangent is $y=4x/\mathrm e$.

Comment: Thank you, you explained it much better than my teacher! :)